# Juniper "show route receive-protocol bgp" output meaning

Tags: bgp, juniper, route

When you show the received route from a specific neighbor in BGP with a Juniper, the output is the following :

```
show route receive-protocol bgp X.X.X.X      

inet.0: V destinations, W routes (X active, Y holddown, Z hidden)
[...]
```

What is the difference beetween "destinations", "routes" and "active", "holddown", "hidden" ?

Which prefixes are put into the GRT and which one are shared in iBGP (full mesh or RR) ?

According to the documentation the "hidden" are the routes that is not used because of a routing policy but this routes are shared in iBGP ?

Edit

Same question for the BGP summary command :

```
show bgp summary 
Threading mode: BGP I/O
Groups: X Peers: Y Down peers: Z
Table          Tot Paths  Act Paths Suppressed    History Damp State    Pending
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think it helps to set the baseline for the general process of how BGP routes are processed, this is true for all vendors.

There are 3 main components:

- ADJ-RIB-IN: This is the table where all received routes from a specific neighbor are stored *prior* to policy processing and BGP path selection.
- LOCAL-RIB: AKA the global routing table.  Routes stored here are the result of import policy processing and BGP path selection.
- ADJ-RIB-OUT: This is the table where all of the best path selected BGP routes destined for a particular neighbor are processed against any export policies and are going to be advertised.

On Junos:

- `show route receive-protocol bgp A.B.C.D` looks at ADJ-RIB-IN
- `show route` looks at the LOCAL-RIB (i.e. routing table)
- `show route advertising-protocol bgp A.B.C.D` looks at ADJ-RIB-OUT

Now that we have that reference, on to your specific questions.

> What is the difference beetween "destinations", "routes" and "active", "holddown", "hidden" ?

The line of output you're referring to is the status of the LOCAL-RIB/Routing Table (inet.0).

```
jhead@R1> show route receive-protocol bgp 192.168.1.1

inet.0: 887870 destinations, 6884733 routes (887867 active, 1 holddown, 3 hidden)
```

The above example basically says that currently in inet.0 (the global routing table) has X number of routes in each status.

- Destinations refer to the number of unique destination prefixes.
- Routes refer to the number of total routes to those prefixes, it
  factors in multiple routes to the same destination.
- Active refers to
  the number of resolved destinations.
- Holddown
  refers to the number of routes that are pending (i.e. not yet
  inactive).
- Hidden refers to the fact that the route cannot be
  resolved for some reason.  That could be due to policy or because it can't reach the next-hop associated with the route.

What your example doesn't show is actual received routes, so I'll extend to the example from above:

```
jhead@R1> show route receive-protocol bgp 192.168.1.1 

inet.0: 887869 destinations, 6884721 routes (887866 active, 1 holddown, 3 hidden)
  Prefix          Nexthop          MED     Lclpref    AS path
  1.0.0.0/24              74.40.0.147          0       80         13335 I
                          74.40.0.226          0       80         13335 I
  1.0.4.0/22              74.40.0.60           0       80         6939 4826 38803 I
                          74.40.0.26           0       80         6939 4826 38803 I
  1.0.4.0/24              74.40.0.60           0       80         6939 4826 38803 I
                          74.40.0.26           0       80         6939 4826 38803 I
```

> Which prefixes are put into the GRT and which one are shared in iBGP (full mesh or RR) ?

Remember, this is the ADJ-RIB-IN, so it shows routes *prior* to policy processing and BGP best path selection.  You need to run `show route` to see what is installed in the routing table.

The `show route advertising-protocol bgp A.B.C.D` can show you what is advertised to a particular neighbor.  The neighbor you run this command for will factor in whether it's IBGP (RR, etc.) or EBGP.

> Same question for the BGP summary command :

Here's a partial example that points to the variables you're asking about:

```
jhead@R1> show bgp summary
Threading mode: BGP I/O
Default eBGP mode: advertise - accept, receive - accept
Groups: 7 Peers: 15 Down peers: 4
<...snip...>
```

- Groups refer to the number of BGP groups that are configured (`set protocols bgp group ABC ...`)
- Peers refer to the total number of BGP peers on the router, regardless of status.
- Down peers refer to the number of BGP peers that are down out of total number of peers.